# Location to executable works locally but not found in remote

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

In my node js app, this is my folder structure.

```
application
    utils
      index.js

    playwright
      chromium-1076
        chrome-mac
          Chromium.app
            Contents
              MacOS
               Chromium
```

In the `index.js` I am doing the following.

```
const a = () => {
    const executablePath = 'playwright/chromium-1076/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium';
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: true,
        executablePath,
    });
}
```

It works fine when I do this locally.

But when I deployed to server, getting following error.

> Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at
> playwright/chromium-1076/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium

Why? That `playwright` folder exists in the project itself.